# I cant understand this access modifier

Tags: c++, access-modifiers

I am the beginner of C++. And I have a programming test today. But I cant understand this examples.

```
class A
{
public:
    int w;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int x;
};

class C : private A
{
public: int y;
};

class D : protected B
{
public: int z;
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.w = 10; // compile error
}
```

I thought (D d; d.w = 10) is correct, but it has compile error.

D derived by B (protected), and B derived by A (public). 
So, I think D can access A class member, because

Class B : public A
{ public:int x} 
==>
Class B
{ public: int w; int x;}

and Class D : protected B 
{ public: int z}
==>
class D
{public: int z; protected: int w, int x;}

Why I am wrong?? Thank you!

Comment: Because of `protected` inheritance, only `D` and classes derived from `D` know that `D` is a `B` and can access `B` and `A` members. `main` is not derived from `D`.

Comment: *"So, I think D can access A class member"* You are correct, but it's `main` that is trying to access `A::w`, not a member function of `D`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`D` can see members of `A` and `B`, but because of `protected` inheritance, only `D` and classes derived from `D` know that `D` is a `B` and can access `B` and `A` members. `main` is not derived from `D`, so `main` is not aware of `D`'s inheritance of `B` and thus cannot access the inherited `A` and `B` members.